# Can a parent function tell if a child has written to stdin?

Tags: c, fork, parent, stdin

For instance let's say the parent function has:

```
scanf("%s", str);
if (strcmp(str,"test")==0)
    printf("Success!\n);
```

and here is the child function:

```
signal(SIGUSR1, speak);
sleep(5);
kill(0, SIGUSR1)
```

and the sleep function is:

```
void speak()
{
    puts("test");
}
```

How come the parent function never reaches success? Is it because `puts` function doesn't write from the keyboard? Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Yes it can, this is very common. Read about *pipes*. Also, read about [`fputs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid pipes. Would fputs() alone work?

Comment: No, it can't, but inasmuch as `stdin` is not a writable stream, the parent can be certain that the child *has not* written either to its own `stdin` or to the parent's.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you want a pipe without using pipes.

Comment: One should not call `puts` (as well as `printf()` & Friends) from a signal handler, as those are not guaranteed to be async-signal save. One could however call `write()`. For details on this see `man 7 signal`.

Comment: The man page for `signal()` on my system: ubuntu linux 14.04, says that `signal()` is unstable and should not be used.   It says to use `sigaction()` instead

Comment: `puts()` writes to `stdout`, why would you expect this to end up in the parent's `stdin` unless you connect them with a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

> How come the parent function never reaches success? Is it because puts function doesn't write from the keyboard? Is there a way I can work around this?

I suppose that you allow the child process to inherit its standard streams from the parent, so that they are shared by parent and child.  You seem to have the very odd idea that data written to `stdout` should feed back to `stdin`.  Although it is possible to arrange for that by creating a pipe and reassigning the standard streams, it is by no means normal to do so, much less automatic.

If you want to perform IPC between two processes via stream I/O, then creating a pipe between them is one of the few ways to do it, and probably the easiest.  Especially so when the processes are related as parent / child.

Answer (score 0):

we can do redirection without using pipe.As far as I understood your target is to print to the stdout by the the child process and reading from the stdin by the parent process.

Here is a solution:
`freopen("myfile.txt","r",stdin);`------>do this at the parent process after the child is created.

`freopen("myfile.txt","w",stdout);`------>do this in child process after the child is created.